# Loading the package('kableExtra')

Tags: r, error-handling, r-markdown, kableextra

I'm a new user to rmarkdown and trying to learn how to format better tables for a report.
I had a report using the package "kableExtra" and it was fine. But now I cannot even load the package anymore and I do not know why.

This is the error I get:

> "package of namespace load failed for 'kableExtra' in
> library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):  DLL 'systemfonts' not
> found: maybe not installed for this architecture?  Execution halted"

Anyone can help me, please?

***I am using RStudio 2022.02.0 Build 443
and R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"***

Thank you :)

> sessionInfo() R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build
> 19042)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252
> LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
> LC_NUMERIC=C                    [5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] dplyr_1.0.8
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] pillar_1.7.0
> compiler_4.1.2    remotes_2.4.2     prettyunits_1.1.1 tools_4.1.2
> testthat_3.1.2    digest_0.6.29      [8] pkgbuild_1.3.1
> pkgload_1.2.4     evaluate_0.15     memoise_2.0.1     lifecycle_1.0.1
> tibble_3.1.6      pkgconfig_2.0.3   [15] rlang_1.0.2       DBI_1.1.2
> cli_3.2.0         rstudioapi_0.13   curl_4.3.2        yaml_2.3.5
> xfun_0.30         [22] fastmap_1.1.0     withr_2.5.0       knitr_1.38
> desc_1.4.1        generics_0.1.2    vctrs_0.3.8       fs_1.5.2
> [29] devtools_2.4.3    rprojroot_2.0.2   tidyselect_1.1.2  glue_1.6.2
> R6_2.5.1          processx_3.5.2    fansi_1.0.2       [36]
> rmarkdown_2.13    sessioninfo_1.2.2 purrr_0.3.4       callr_3.7.0
> magrittr_2.0.2    usethis_2.1.5     ps_1.6.0          [43]
> ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.2   assertthat_0.2.1  utf8_1.2.2
> cachem_1.0.6      crayon_1.5.1      brio_1.1.3

Comment: Try running `install.packages("systemfonts")`. The error message indicates there may be a problem with that package. What OS are you running?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that, still not working and same error message. And I included sessionInfo() above. I'm using Windows.

Comment: You didn't mention what operating system you are using. Was there any output from `install.packages("systemfonts")`? What exactly did it say? Does `library(systemfonts)` return the same error?

Comment: library(systemfonts)
Error: package ‘systemfonts’ is not installed for 'arch = x64'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘systemfonts’ was built under R version 4.1.3

Comment: Somehow your install of `systemfonts` is incorrect. Running `install.packages("systemfonts")` should have updated it. I guess you could try `remove.packages("systemfonts")` first and then retry the install. Make extra sure no errors occur. What does `options('repos')$repos["CRAN"]` return? Are you using a different mirror than the default?

Comment: options('repos')$repos["CRAN"]
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/"

Comment: I couldn't remove the package...

Comment: > remove.packages("systemfonts")
Removing package from ‘C:/Users/cnetto/OneDrive - Harbour Air/Documents/R/R-4.1.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in remove.packages :
  cannot delete reparse point 'C:/Users/cnetto/OneDrive - Harbour Air/Documents/R/R-4.1.2/library/systemfonts/libs', reason 'There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point'

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your Windows One Drive configuration. That's not really an R thing. Maybe try restarting your computer? For whatever reason OneDrive doesn't play well with R. Here's a guide for creating a folder outside of OneDrive: https://mattwthomas.com/blog/r-fix-onedrive/ or here https://medium.com/@ValidScience/how-to-fix-rstudios-package-installation-on-windows-10-c1e602bf3a1f

Comment: Thank you, MrFlick!
It's running all good now. 

It was the Cloud synced folder. I checked the links you sent and follow the steps on this one: https://mattwthomas.com/blog/r-fix-onedrive/